# Найти самое длинное слово в строке

Tags: c

Пытаюсь написать программу в которой надо ввести строку, а после её ввода найти в ней самое длинное слово.

Вот мой код :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char pib[100];
  char *pib2[3];
  int i = 1;
  gets(pib);
  char *str = strtok(pib, " ");
  pib2[0] = str;
  while(str != NULL)
  {
      str = strtok(NULL, " ");
      pib2[i] = str;
      i++;
  }
  int k, max, maxNum = 0;
  for(k = 0; k < 3; k++)
  {
      int size = strlen(pib2[k]);
      if(maxNum < size)
      {
          maxNum = size;
          max = k;
      }
  }
  printf("%s", pib2[max]);
  return 0;
}
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы удалили старый вопрос, а могли бы просто поменять метку.

Логика такая:

1 Сначала разбиваем строку на литералы

2 Ищем максимум

Ввод строки я думаю Вы организуете сами.

Повторю ответ :

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    char orig[] = "Zero Two One Five Maximum, Min.RRR;Noone";
    size_t max_lenght = 0;
    char* max_word = NULL;

    char* tmp_word = strtok (orig,",. ;\t");

    while (tmp_word != NULL)
    {
        size_t l = strlen(tmp_word);
        if (l > max_lenght) {
            max_lenght = l;
            max_word = tmp_word;
        }
        printf("%s\n", tmp_word);
        tmp_word = strtok (NULL, ",. ;\t");
    }

    printf ("%s : %ld\n",max_word, max_lenght);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а если строка будет: Zero Two One,Maximum,Five (частично без пробелов вместе с запятыми) ? или ещё вариант где одно слово будет иметь столько же символов что и слово рядом но вместе с запятой которое просто разделилось пробелами через strtok ?(это если учесть что всё таки правильная строка будет)

Comment: @noname2019 Добрый вечер, да, может быть и такой кейс, я внес изменения ))) смотрите)

Comment: Приветствую. Вы бы ещё вынесли инициализацию "size_t l"  над циклом и в цикле использовали один участок памяти (перезаписывая его) вместо выделения новой для каждой итерации (или же я не правильно понимаю этот участок кода). Ведь слов то может быть много...

Comment: @noname2019 там все будет нормально

Comment: Я бы еще добавил проверку -- `if (max_word) ...` перед печатью. Или написал такой `printf("%s : %ld\n", max_word ? max_word : "empty string", max_length);`

Comment: @avp уважаемый товарищ, я думаю, что Вы согласитесь со мной - тут можно накостылить столько проверок, что строк 100 будет. Для полноценного(в рамках заданного вопроса) варианта решения проблемы автора, данного кода достаточно)

Comment: @Andrey, а вот лишние буквы типа `UNUSED` совсем не нужны (дурные примеры подаете -))

Comment: @avp  -Wunused-variable  стоит или тут в правилах написано что запрещено в ответах использовать макросы, атрибуты, флаги компилятора ?

Comment: @Andrey, тут ничего не запрещено, пишите как вам нравится

Comment: @avp ответьте пожалуйста, если бы я написал __attribute__((unused)) за место макроса, как бы Вы отреагировали ?))))

Comment: @Andrey, точно так же (imho ни к чему загромождать код лишним текстом) / Впрочем, все мы тут развлекаемся кто как может -)

Comment: @avp и правильно делаем :))) иначе все мержди были бы без обсуждения :D